# How to run .aspx page in IIS on Windows XP SP2

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-xp

I want to set an ASP.Net Server (IIS) in my Desktop to run my asp.net .aspx pages. I'm currently using Win XP Service Pack 2. To install the IIS, first I inserted the XP cd to the disk drive and then I follow the following path `Control Panel / Add or Remove Programs / Add/Remove Windows Components`. I successfully installed IIS on this computer. Then for running the asp.net .aspx page I need to run the following code in Command Prompt:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

When I run this line in command prompt then it shows me the following error:

> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.5\aspnet_regiis.exe' is not recognized as
>    an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

After this I checked for the `aspnet_regiis.exe` in the path `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.5\` but here `aspnet_regiis.exe` is not available in that folder. I'm not able to understand it.

Comment: Which IDE are you using to develop this web application? is this your development machine?

Comment: visual studio 2008 Pro, .Net Framework 3.5, c#

Answer (score 2):

You need to install [.NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22) first!

XP SP2 doesn't have it by default

Comment: i have already install .Net Framework 3.5 but still aspnet_regiis.exe is not found in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.5\   folder

Comment: try use the one in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

Answer (score 0):

You need to install .Net Framework first. You can download v3.5 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22)

Comment: i have already install .Net Framework 3.5 but still aspnet_regiis.exe is not found in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.5\   folder

Comment: Is your Window 64 bit? Then the path might be `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v3.5\ `

Answer (score 0):

You need to run from

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
```

check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.90).aspx#findingthecorrectversion)

[image]

Comment: yes i found it in %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 and i run it, and it is run successfully but in the next step when i try to run the following code :                                        "regsvr32 %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll"       then it show the following error  "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found. The file can not be registered.

Comment: Which steps are you following?

Comment: 1st i open the command prompt and here i typed "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i" After it finishes, then in 2nd step i Open 'Run' from 'Start Menu' and type: "regsvr32 %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" then it show the erro i.e. "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found. The file can not be registered.